# Selecting a subset of tables from an existing database in Code First approach using reverse engineer

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am starting a new ASP.NET MVC 4 internet app and would like to use the code first with an existing database approach to generate my models. But it turns out to be a very big database, from which I just would like to pick a small subset of tables.

Is it possible yo reverse engineer just a subset of tables from an existing database?

Comment: The reverese engineer of my whole database has come to an end after a while. I may opt to do some clean-up and use just the model classes I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do a hybrid approach and initially pull your model using data first.  Then switch to code first and implement the unit of work pattern to only expose entities from the tables in which you are interested.

Comment: Thanks. I guess it will be a matter of time that this feature is added to EF Power Tools (maybe in the RTM it is included), just like it is when creating the model (edmx) from an existing database (there you can pick the tables, views, sps...)